# Why isn't this LESS CSS being applied?

Tags: javascript, html, css, less

Why isn't this stylehseet being loaded?  The background color for one should be something akin to `cadetblue`.

My page with home.less.css linked can be found at: http://adl.sdf.org/home.shtml

Comment: The link tag should be <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="home.less.css">

Comment: This question will not be usable to future users in its current state, once your website is fixed. Can you please post some code here illustrating what is wrong right now? Otherwise, this question should be closed as "too localized"

Comment: Oh, I see what you meant.  Sorry about that.  How about if we post it after we figure out what the issue is, because honestly I have no idea which parts are the problematic ones.

Comment: post the whole head section of your HTML document here, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line `<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="home.less.css">` in your `<head>` tag instead of inside the `<body>` tag like given below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
/* Add head block in your HTML */
<head> 
   <meta charset="utf-8"> 
   <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="home.less.css">
   <title>!eugaeL eht nioJ ~ !eugaeL eht nioJ ~ !eugaeL eht nioJ</title>
   <script src="lib/html5shiv.js"></script>
   <script src="lib/less.js"></script>
</head>
```

**And Your HTML Should look like as given below:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="home.less.css">
        <title>!eugaeL eht nioJ ~ !eugaeL eht nioJ ~ !eugaeL eht nioJ</title>
        <script src="lib/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/less.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/jq_w_plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="home.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/forkit.js"></script><script>
          $('.forkit-curtain').css({position: 'absolute', bottom: 0, left: 0, margin: '-1.5in 0 0'});
        </script>
        <style>.prefetch { display: none; } </style>
    </head>
<body>
    /* Body Contents */
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're incredible!http://adl.sdf.org/lessdiag/home.shtml

Answer (score 0):

this is your css link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/less" href="home.less.css">
```

here's what it should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="home.less.css">
```

Comment: I believe you are wrong: see [here](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/dist/less-1.3.0.js#L3162) and [here](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/dist/less-1.3.0.js#L3167)

Comment: I've now changed it to what you said, with no difference: [http://adl.sdf.org/home.shtml](here)

Comment: @adlwalrus: no change in above link.

Comment: @A.K I think that's due to some javascript that does the styling

Comment: oop! sorry about that, but my point still stands.